# PHP Session with Adobe Air application?

Tags: php, session, air

I don't have a lot of experience with either PHP or Adobe AIR. I'm just researching at the moment. I am considering creating some kind of internal AIR app. It would basically be a web chat interface that can be minimized to the tray, with the ability to notify users of new messages, etc. In other words, a pretty basic web chat application. This would be my first AIR app, so it's mostly for me to learn.

I'm wondering how you would maintain some kind of session state in the AIR application (to display users online, in chats, etc.) Does the AIR app work the same as a visiting a web page in a browser? I can't seem to find any information on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find it easier to pass the session ID as a url parameter. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php For more info on this.